# MAC mysql host and ruby mysql gem

Tags: mysql, ruby

If I list my the mysql port I get...

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
...
mysqld     1468   marklocklear   10u  IPv4 0xa20755c85d1b929      0t0    TCP localhost:8889 (LISTEN)
```

I have a ruby script where I am trying to connect to mysql and I have...

```
con = Mysql.new 'localhost:8889', 'root', 'password', 'brewery'
```

I am getting the error...

```
script.rb:4:in `new': Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:8889' (0) (Mysql::Error)
```

I have also tried all manner of `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` in addtion to adding ports. I am running MAMP Pro on Mac if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ruby the port should be the fifth argument. Try:

con = Mysql.new 'localhost', 'root', 'password', 'brewery', 8889

Comment: You rock dude! I was wondering if you could specify a port as an argument, but could not find any documentation anywhere.